# Oracle db stops working frequently

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

Recently, I faced a problem with Oracle 11g. It stops working frequently, every few hours, and respectively, must be started again. This was never happened before, it just began during last month.

Here is the content of clsc.log file

```
2016-10-06 07:00:14.344: [ default][2031720192]utgdv:2:ocr loc file /etc/oracle/olr.loc cannot be opened. errno 2
[    CLSE][2031720192]clse_get_crs_home: Error retrieving OLR configuration [0] [Error opening olr.loc file. No such file or directory]
```

Can anyone help me?

Edit: There is alert log messages like here, each time instance has stopped working (In this case, it has stopped working on Wed night and started again on Thu)

```
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 35012 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 2 seq# 35012 mem# 0: /home/db/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/redo02.log
Wed Oct 05 18:53:08 2016
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 35013 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 3 seq# 35013 mem# 0: /home/db/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/redo03.log
Wed Oct 05 19:05:08 2016
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 35014 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 1 seq# 35014 mem# 0: /home/db/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/redo01.log
Wed Oct 05 19:15:03 2016
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 35015 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 2 seq# 35015 mem# 0: /home/db/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/redo02.log
Thu Oct 06 06:41:11 2016
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Picked latch-free SCN scheme 3
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on. 
.
.
.
```

Comment: What is `clsc.log`?  That doesn't obviously register as an Oracle database log file.  What is in the alert log?

Comment: @JustinCave alert log messages added above.